# MySql is returning column name, not value

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT 'USED' FROM `KEYS` WHERE `KEYS`.`KEY` = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'"

Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            While (myReader.Read())
                MessageBox.Show(myReader.GetString(0))
            End While
```

The returning string is *`"USED"`*. But that is wrong: it should be returning integer `0` instead. Why is that?

*Edit*: I changed the MessageBox line to `MessageBox.Show(myReader.GetInt16(0))` but now it sends me an error telling me that the input string is not in the right format..

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks: Ah, you are very right. I am quite new to this.. I will take a look about that soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need backtick, not apostrophe ` not '

You're actually selecting the string "USED" rather than the column. You could just remove the apostrophes all together and say

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT USED FROM `KEYS` WHERE `KEYS`.`KEY` = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
```

Also as a note, don't use dynamic SQL--used prepared queries:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT USED FROM KEYS WHERE KEYS.KEY = @Key";
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Key", TextBox1.Text);
```

Otherwise you're very susceptible to SQL injection (which is a very bad thing).

Comment: Thanks a lot! What does the Pameters.AddWithValue method do exactly though?

Comment: It adds a parameter of a given name, in this case `@Key`, with the value passed, in this case `TextBox1.Text` to the query. When the query executes, it safely inserts that value where you've put the name of that parameter in the command text, so that you don't have to worry about somebody executing SQL code on your app without your permission.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong quotes; you need to use ` as so:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT `USED` FROM `KEYS` WHERE `KEYS`.`KEY` = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'USED' and write used instead.

Answer (score 1):

single quoted around the name 'USED' tell it to return the word 'USED' in an unnamed column.

Answer (score 0):

Change here

```
"SELECT `USED` FROM `KEYS` WHERE `KEYS`.`KEY` = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
```

You need to insert backticks and not single quotes.